# Having an issue pulling the correct dates in a query for when certain events happen in between

Tags: sql, max, min

Attached is the table for a unit history showing events and dates for that unit.  I'm trying to write a query that pulls the latest start date for when that unit is ready, the status can either be 'vacant rented ready' or 'vacant unrented ready'.

My issue is that when the status is in 'ready' it can then be put to a 'not ready' status, and I want to be able to pull the latest 'ready' status date when this happens.  In example 1, the start date of 01/28/19 with the status of 'vacant unrented ready' means that this person moved out, then the unit became ready on '03/05/19', I can pull this query no problem.

But in example 2, the next person moved out on 05/18/20, and the unit became ready on 06/08/20, but it then went back into a 'not ready' status and truly became ready on 07/10/20.  I want to be able to account for when this happens and am not sure how to.  I'd like to be able to pull all the true ready dates for this unit.

[image: unit_status table]

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the most recent status for a unit and to see if it matches some set of values.  You can do this with:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.startdate = (select max(t2.startdate)
                     from t t2
                     where t2.user = t.user
                    ) and
      t.status in ('Vacant rented ready', 'Vacant unrented ready');
```